# When Cordova app is reinstalled or updated from Google Play, is localStorage cleared?

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-play, local-storage

I have a Cordova app on Google Play that utilizes `localStorage`. In the new version of it, the same keys are used, but the expected values are different. This means that if an old value is encountered, there may be problems.

An obvious solution is to have a `version` variable that tracks the app's version. If the stored value is the same as the app's current version, do nothing, else update the value and clear `localStorage`.

However, is that even needed? I have noticed that when I reinstall the app for debugging purposes, `localStorage` is sometimes cleared.

**Does an update on Google Play guarantee fresh `localStorage`?**

**When exactly is `localStorage` cleared?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On both Android and iOS, local storage values are preserved if the app is **updated** but not if the app is **reinstalled** (first uninstalled then installed).

Note that on iOS, local storage of a Cordova app may also be cleared at any time if the device runs low on space - Apple considers it to be a local cache.

Comment: So if I roll an update in which old `localStorage` values cause problems, I should implement something to clear the data, right?

Comment: Correct. You could use a boolean flag, version number, etc.